# Headless Browser in Azure Notebook

Tags: python, azure, phantomjs, jupyter-notebook, casperjs

I want to scrape a website which content is generated by Javascript dynamically. The web scraping is executed on [Microsoft Azure Notebook](https://notebooks.azure.com/) so that I can continue processing it via Python and Jupyter.

Therefore, a headless browser is needed to render the content during web scraping. I'm thinking either [PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org/) or [CasperJS](http://casperjs.org/) but they require installation with root permission, and I cannot install it.

What else option can I use in Azure Notebook for dynamically generated content?

Comment: Hey man, this is a very interesting question, I am disappointed to see you didnt get a better response, I am also facing a simialr challenge and havent received much support, dont know if you can perhaps share your experience here on my thread over [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51091813/etl-from-secure-websites-to-sql-database-on-azure)